# Keras' Tokenizer vs sklearn's CountVectorizer

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a big pile of raw-text documents.

I am not sure whether to use **keras.text_preprocessing.Tokenizer** or **sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer**. Any idea, suggestions? Which is faster? Do they have any major difference that I might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: You can go ahead `keras.text_preprocessing.Tokenizer`. with that you can scale your structure as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goal and your machine.

If you have  a few CPUs and/or GPU(s), then `keras` can utilize them and run faster. From another hand scikit-learn methods have more options, for example they can find ngrams, while `keras.text_preprocessing.Tokenizer` has fewer parameters.

Answer (score 1):

sklearn.CountVectorizer gives values like 0 1 0 1
1 means present ; 0 means not present

keras.Tokenizer give index's of the words: 0 3 2 4

[["He is good player"],["He is is basketball player"]]

Count Vectorizer: He is good player basketball
[[1   1  1    1      0]

```
             [1   2  0    1      1]]
```

Tokenizer:
{"OOV":1,"He":2,"is":3,"good":4,"player":5,"basketball":6}

[[2 3 4 5]

[2 3 6 5]]

Tokenizer works similar to dictionary indexing

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late for an answer, but I have been working on this issue for the last couple of weeks.

The short answer is that both approaches should yield the same number of vocabulary (tokenized words). So, this is also a measure of success in case *CountVectorizer* produces a different number of tokenized words (corpus vocabulary) from its peer *Keras Tokenizer*. I have written a couple of lines to check the results between the two approaches. Basically, I implemented the two approaches and compared their results.

As a rule of thumb I would suggest you do the same thing to see for yourself if they yield the same result. Remember to keep the *CounterVectorizer* on its default arguments and don't filter out infrequent, or frequent tokens with the `min_df`, `max_df` arguments. So do something like

```
def corpus_split(s):
    return s.split(' ')
c_vectorizer=CountVectorizer(tokenizer=corpus_split, max_df=1.0, min_df=1)
```

This will help you to compare the results because *Keras Tokenizer* by default takes into account all the tokens of your text.

Now for the matter of time efficiency, I don't have a specific insight to give you. My suggestion is to try both and see for yourself. Implementation of both approaches are found online.

Hope that I helped you, and also anyone else who will notice the question.